# How can I clean a gas oven's cabinet of rodent debris?

Tags: kitchens, cleaning, pest-control, gas-stove

We found mouse droppings in the house and got a pest control company to use poison baits to get rid of it. We have cleared the house of the droppings. However, we found droppings in the gas oven bottom rack.

The access is very limited and we need some guidance on how to get it cleaned out well.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: A vacuum with a small hose attached to the big hose should work.  Duct tape to the rescue.

Comment: Also, after physical cleaning, I'd recommend swabbing the area with diluted bleach (e.g., with a non-woven wipe stapled to a stick), then drying *thoroughly*. You might also sprinkle sodium bicarbonate (baking soda) on the bottom. It's non-poisonous, but irritating to little critters.

Comment: I would not put sodium bicarbonate on metal parts because over time I think it would cause corrosion. I have heard that mice and rats cannot stand the odor of peppermint. You could put some peppermint extract on pieces of paper towel and lay in on the floor under the stove.  You could put snap traps under the stove before you try the peppermint.

Comment: If the openings the mice got into the house through were not fixed, you ***will*** have more mice. Poisioning and calling it solved is essentially setting you up to need pest control over and over on a repeating basis, forever.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Or just heat it up well before use. Inside an oven can get hot enough to sterilise surface contamination, no need for bleach in a place where you can't reach to rinse it off

Comment: Depends on if it was your outdoor cat's fault. And then it went and died in there. That's new stove time. You're lucky if it's just some droppings and they haven't been *living* in it. There's only one solution to *ungodly smell comes when I turn the oven on.* Because you can't break the unit down far enough to get to the inside of the inside.

Answer (score 2):

Most oven doors can be removed through their hinges. See if yours can via looking up the instruction manual - I'm sure it can. Once removed you should have more room to navigate and clean after removing the grills.

A bottle brush, shoe brush and an old tooth brush are handy cleaning tools to have for such situations. I bought this combo below from Amazon which attaches to a vacuum. The brush is great too.

Once the debris is removed you can use a disinfectant spray

[image: Flexible hose]

Comment: Depending on the location, western and/or south western US(?), the dust raised by brushing is not good for you, without a good mask.  Hava(something virus)/mouse virus.

Comment: @crip659 Hantavirus I think

Answer (score 1):

Mouse droppings can spread disease, and you should be careful handling/cleaning them. Gloves are a must and many professionals would recommend using an N95 respirator when during cleaning to avoid inhaling particulate from the droppings.

It’s unlikely that the poison will eliminate your problem. You may need to set traps and seal holes to ensure mice do not return.

However, as far as cleaning goes, the CDC has a decent guide: https://www.cdc.gov/healthypets/pets/wildlife/clean-up.html

Bleach is a good disinfectant in a 1:5 or 1:10 ratio. Follow the instructions on the product for disinfection, and make sure to use water to rinse bleach off any metal surfaces after the disinfection period to prevent damage.

As far as accessing the droppings, consider sliding your oven away from the wall. I’m not sure if you’ll be able to slide the oven fully out, but it may allow for easier access to the space where the droppings are found, and you should inspect behind all your kitchen appliances and cabinets for holes that may need to be filled to prevent your intruders.